# Are Primitive Wrapper Classes in Java Treated as Reference Types?

Tags: java, reference, wrapper

From [Java in a Nutshell, 2.10 Reference Types](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_10.htm),

> Java does not manipulate objects and arrays directly. Instead, it
>   manipulates references to objects and arrays. Because Java handles
>   objects and arrays by reference, classes and array types are known as
>   reference types. In contrast, Java handles values of the primitive
>   types directly, or by value.

But from the following, it appears that primitive wrapper classes (Objects) are actually handled by value rather than reference,

```
> Integer foo = new Integer(1);
> Integer bar = foo;
> bar = new Integer(2);
> foo
1
```

So is it true that the quote from above is not quite right?

---

**UPDATE:** My confusion came from misunderstanding the distinction between my code snippet above and something like the following:

```
> import java.util.LinkedList;
> LinkedList<Integer> foo = new LinkedList<Integer>();
> foo.add(1);
> LinkedList<Integer> bar = foo;
> bar.remove(); 
> System.out.println(foo.size());
0
> System.out.println(bar.size());
0
```

Where in this latter case, `bar.remove()` actually operates on the LinkedList to which both `foo` and `bar` reference.

Comment: You assign to `bar`, and `foo` doesn't change.  That doesn't distinguish between references and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive class wrappers are object references, not primitive types.

In your example, you're assigning a new value to your variable, not updating the state. That's why `foo` keeps its *old* value (old because it was never changed):

```
Integer foo = new Integer(1);
Integer bar = foo; //bar and foo "points" to the same location
bar = new Integer(2); //now bar only "points" to a new location, foo is unaffected
System.out.println(foo);
```

You can easily test this by using `==` and `equals` comparison:

```
Integer a = 128;
Integer b = 128;
System.out.println(a == b); //false
System.out.println(a.equals(b)); //true
```

Comment: Let's be very careful when using `==` to ascertain things; wrapper types have a built-in cache for values in the range -128 and 127. So replacing 128 in the above example with 127 will print `true` for both.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma I know that. That's why I use 128 for example and not 127, which is explained in other Q/As.

Answer (score 1):

Your code fragment does not demonstrate that the wrappers behave like value types: in fact, they are reference types, and they are immutable.

```
Integer foo = new Integer(1); // foo references an object wrapping 1
Integer bar = foo;            // bar references the same object as foo
bar = new Integer(2);         // bar references an object wrapping 2;
                              // continues to reference 1
```

A simple way to see what happens with primitive wrappers is to compare them for equality using `==` operator instead of calling `equals`. You need to be careful to avoid comparing wrappers of small numbers, though, because they are cached for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What the quote you linked to is referring to is field access and array access expressions. Those need to go through a reference value to determine the underlying object.

The `=` operator is known as the [assignment operator.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1) In your case, it's not a field access expression, nor an array access expression, so we fall to the third case

> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression
>     completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not
>     evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>     for the same reason and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the left-hand variable, is subjected to value set conversion
>     (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an
>     extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is
>     stored into the variable.

So in

```
bar = new Integer(2);
```

the `bar` is evaluated and produces a variable, itself. Then, `new Integer(2)` must be evaluated. That is a [new instance creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9). It produces an instance whose value is a [reference value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3)

> The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
>   objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

Once that value is generated, it is assigned to `bar`.

Note how `foo` was never involved.